# Perform a drag and drop in serenity-js

Tags: drag-and-drop, serenity-js

I'm searching for a way to perform a drag and drop with serenity-js (http://serenity-js.org/) but I can't find any examples. What I can find is the protractor way, but because protractor is baked in the serenity-js framework I was wondering how to get this working. (Sorry I'm a novice in TS and javascript)

### UPDATE:

I implemented the HTML5 workaround from Jan Molak but I got the following error message:
[image]

And this is my Task implementation:

```
import { Execute, Target } from 'serenity-js/lib/screenplay-protractor';

import { PerformsTasks, Task } from 'serenity-js/lib/screenplay';

const dragAndDropScript = require('html-dnd').code; // tslint:disable-
line:no-var-requires

 export class DragAndDrop implements Task {

 static with(draggable: Target, dropzone: Target) {
    return new DragAndDrop(draggable, dropzone);
 }

 performAs(actor: PerformsTasks): PromiseLike<void> {
    return actor.attemptsTo(
        Execute.script(dragAndDropScript).withArguments(this.draggable, 
 this.dropzone)
    );
 }

 constructor(private draggable: Target, private dropzone: Target) {
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no built-in [interaction](http://serenity-js.org/design/screenplay-pattern.html#interaction) for that just yet, but Serenity/JS is quite easy to extend, so you could create a custom interaction (and maybe even submit it as a [pull request](https://github.com/jan-molak/serenity-js)?).

Below are the steps I'd take to create a custom interaction.

### 1. Research the protractor way

To start with, think about how you'd implement this functionality using the plain-old Protractor?

[Protractor's API documentation](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions) suggests the following options:

```
// Dragging one element to another.
browser.actions().
    mouseDown(element1).
    mouseMove(element2).
    mouseUp().
    perform();

// You can also use the `dragAndDrop` convenience action.
browser.actions().
    dragAndDrop(element1, element2).
    perform();

// Instead of specifying an element as the target, you can specify an offset
// in pixels. This example double-clicks slightly to the right of an element.
browser.actions().
    mouseMove(element).
    mouseMove({x: 50, y: 0}).
    doubleClick().
    perform();
```

As you can see, all the above examples rely on the `browser.actions()` API, so we'll need to find a way of getting hold of that.

But before diving there, let's try to design our new interaction from the outside-in, and think about the interface we'd like to have.

### 2. Define a DSL you'd like to use

Let's say I wanted to have a Serenity/JS, Screenplay-style interaction based on the second example from the Protractor docs:

```
browser.actions().
    dragAndDrop(element1, element2).
    perform();
```

providing the following interface:

```
actor.attemptsTo(
    DragAndDrop(element1).onto(element2);
)
```

This means that I could define my interaction's DSL as follows:

```
import { Target } from 'serenity-js/lib/screenplay-protractor';

export const DragAndDrop = (draggable: Target) => ({
    onto: (dropzone: Target) => ...
})
```

This will give me the syntax of `DragAndDrop(draggable).onto(dropzone)` that I wanted to have.

The next step is for `DragAndDrop(draggable).onto(dropzone)` call to return an actual interaction.

### 3. Define the interaction

You can define an interaction using the following short-hand syntax:

```
import { Interaction } from 'serenity-js/lib/screenplay-protractor';

Interaction.where(`#actor drags ${draggable} onto ${dropzone}`, actor => {
    // interaction body
});
```

Serenity/JS provides an "[ability](http://serenity-js.org/design/screenplay-pattern.html#ability)" to [`BrowseTheWeb`](https://github.com/jan-molak/serenity-js/blob/f6f818c7e803806635f79537d7dfdd87ff037d18/packages/serenity-js/src/serenity-protractor/screenplay/abilities/browse_the_web.ts). 
This ability is a [Screenplay Pattern](http://serenity-js.org/design/screenplay-pattern.html)-style wrapper around the `protractor` object, which means that you can use it to access protractor-specific APIs.

So provided that you've given your actor the ability to `BrowseTheWeb`:

```
import { Actor, BrowseTheWeb } from 'serenity-js/lib/screenplay-protractor';

const Alice = Actor.named('Alice').whoCan(BrowseTheWeb.using(protractor.browser));
```

you can access it in your `interaction body`:

```
Interaction.where(`#actor drags ${draggable} onto ${dropzone}`, actor => {
    return BrowseTheWeb.as(actor).actions().
        dragAndDrop(..., ...).
        perform();
});
```

One more missing step is that protractor's `browser.actions.dragAndDrop(..., ...)` method expects you to provide an instance of a `WebElement`, rather than a Serenity/JS-specific `Target`.

This means that we need to resolve the `Target` before we pass it on:

```
Interaction.where(`#actor drags ${draggable} onto ${dropzone}`, actor => {

    const browse           = BrowseTheWeb.as(actor),
          draggableElement = browse.locate(draggable),
          dropzoneElement  = browse.locate(dropzone);

    return browse.actions().
        dragAndDrop(draggableElement, dropzoneElement).
        perform();
});
```

### 4. Putting it all together

Given all the above, the resulting implementation could look as follows:

```
import { Actor, BrowseTheWeb, Interaction, Target } from 'serenity-js/lib/screenplay-protractor';

export const DragAndDrop = (draggable: Target) => ({
    onto: (dropzone: Target) => Interaction.where(
        `#actor drags ${draggable} onto ${dropzone}`,
        actor => {
            const browse           = BrowseTheWeb.as(actor),
                  draggableElement = browse.locate(draggable),
                  dropzoneElement  = browse.locate(dropzone);

            return browse.actions().
                dragAndDrop(draggableElement, dropzoneElement).
                perform();
    })
})
```

### HTML5 Drag and Drop and Chrome

Please note that the above implementation might not work in Chromedriver with [HTML5 drag and drop](https://html5demos.com/drag/) unless [this defect](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=841) is fixed.

Alternatively, you can install the [html-dnd](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-dnd) module and implement a Screenplay-style task as follows (you'll need Serenity/JS 1.9.3 or later):

```
import { Execute, Target, Task } from 'serenity-js/lib/screenplay-protractor';

const dragAndDropScript = require('html-dnd').code; // tslint:disable-line:no-var-requires

export const DragAndDrop = (draggable: Target) => ({
    onto: (dropzone: Target) => Task.where(`#actor drags ${draggable} onto ${dropzone}`,
        Execute.script(dragAndDropScript).withArguments(draggable, dropzone),
    ),
});
```

Hope this helps and thanks for joining the Serenity/JS community :-)

Jan

Comment: could  please look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57818817/how-to-assert-that-web-element-is-visible-on-the-screen-using-serenity-js