# How to assert that web element is visible on the screen using serenity-js?

Tags: typescript, automation, protractor, serenity-bdd, serenity-js

I am using Serenity-js BDD framework with screenplay pattern in my project. Here I am not able to perform assertion for visibility of an element on web-page using Ensure class's "that" method.

**Code :**

**Page Element -**

```
static searchPatientsVerificationRow = Target.the('verification record').located(by.xpath("//div[@class='row']//tr"));
```

**Test Script Step :**

```
return Ensure.that(TaggingSearchControls.searchPatientsVerificationRow,Is.visible())
```

**Error :**

> Argument of type 'SuccessCondition' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Assertion'.
>   Property 'answeredBy' is missing in type 'SuccessCondition' but required in type 'Assertion'

Comment: @janmolak : Can you please help me with this ?

Comment: Hi Pritam, what version of Sanity/JS are you using please?

Comment: @JanMolak : I am using "serenity-js": "^1.10.13"

Comment: @JanMolak : For Assertions - "@serenity-js/assertions": "^2.0.1-alpha.2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the code sample you posted might be using a mixture of Serenity/JS 1.x and 2.x syntax.

With [Serenity/JS version 2](https://github.com/jan-molak/serenity-js/tree/2.0), which you can get by installing the following dependencies ([see an example](https://github.com/jan-molak/serenity-js/tree/2.0/examples/protractor-cucumber)):

```
npm install --save-dev @serenity-js/core@next @serenity-js/assertions@next @serenity-js/protractor@next @serenity-js/serenity-bdd@next
```

you'd write it as follows:

```js
// in page object file
import { Target } from '@serenity-js/protractor';
import { by } from 'protracter';

class TaggingSearchControls {
    static searchPatientsVerificationRow =
        Target.the('verification record').located(by.xpath("//div[@class='row']//tr"));
}

// in test file
import { Ensure } from '@serenity-js/assertions';
import { isVisible } from '@serenity-js/protractor';

Ensure.that(TaggingSearchControls.searchPatientsVerificationRow, isVisible())
```

With Serenity/JS version 1 you'd need to extract a `WebElement` from the `Target` first:

```
Ensure.that(WebElement.of(TaggingSearchControls.searchPatientsVerificationRow), Is.Visible())
```

Hope this helps!

Jan

Comment: I have tried  "Ensure.that(WebElement.of(TaggingSearchControls.searchPatientsVerificationRow), Is.Visible())"  .... But there is a problem ... The WebElement class don't have the "OF" method

Comment: It Say's "Property 'of' does not exist on type 'typeof WebElement'.ts(2339)"

Comment: Yes, so there is a class called WebElement in Serenity/JS v1 that used to be responsible for extracting the Webdriver's WebElement from a Target class (note that both classes are called WebElement, which is why you couldn't find the `of` method on the WebDriver one). In Serenity/JS v2 the assertions like `isVisible()` work with the Targets, so there's no need to extract the WebElement any more. I'd suggest to go with Serenity/JS v2 and remove the dependency on Serenity/JS v1 from your project. Have a look at the https://github.com/jan-molak/serenity-js/tree/2.0/examples/protractor-cucumber